# Image frames to video

Tags: python, image, video, opencv

I've tried using all the approaches already mentioned here but none of them are working for whatever reason.

```
import cv2
import os
import glob



path = '.../Desktop/Plot/'
os.chdir(path)
# video_name = 'video.avi'

width=640 
height=400 
size = (width,height)

img_array = []
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(path+'*.png')):
    img = cv2.imread(path+filename+'.png')
    img_array.append(img)



out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

I don't see any thing particularly wrong with this code but all it does is put a 6 kb file in the folder that doesn't play.

Comment: BTW: you could use `write()` in first `for`-loop without creating `img_array`

Comment: if .png images have size different then `640x400` then you have to `resize()` them. If you try to write images with wrong size then it will create empty video.

Comment: are you sure you have to add `.png` and `path` to `filename` ? Maybe you create not existing name with double `path` and double `.png` - `path/path/image.png.png`.

Comment: if you change directory - `os.chdir(path)` then you don't have to add `path` to filename because it is relative `path` and it will try to find images in different folder then you expect.

Comment: most systems don't know path `...` - it may have to be two dots `..` or `../..`

Comment: Good points, I will fix them and hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see many instakes in code.

**1)** most systems doesn't know path `...` which you have in `'.../Desktop/Plot/'` and it may need to be `..` or `../..` instead of `...`

**2)** you use relative `path` - `'.../Desktop/Plot/'` and when you use `os.chdir()` to change directory then relative path with current folder will create path

```
../Desktop/Plot/../Desktop/Plot/
```

and it is not correct path.

**3)** `glob.glob(path+'*.png')` will create `filenames` with `path` and `.png` but you add `path` and `.png` to read image in `imread()` - so you get filename with double `path` and dougle extension

```
 ../Desktop/Plot/../Desktop/Plot/filename.png.png
```

use `print(path+filename+'.png')` to see what you try to read.

BTW: `cv2` doesn't raise error when it can't read image but it return empty frame/image and you can get error when it try to modify empty image.

**4)** if images have size different than `640x400` then it will create empty video because it doesn't resize images when you save in video. You have to manually resize images before save in file

```
 img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
```

**BTW** some decoders don't work with some file extensions - for example `'DIVX'` will not save in file with textension `.mov`

**BTW** you can do all with one `for`-loop and without `img_array`

---

My version

```
import cv2
import os
import glob

path = '../Desktop/Plot/'

#print(os.getcwd())

width = 640 
height = 400 

out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, (width,height))

for filename in sorted(glob.glob(path + '*.png')):
    print(filename)

    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))

    out.write(img)

out.release()
```

Comment: Thank you for point me in the right direction! I tried implementing your version but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: printing out the filename does give the right file path so im not sure if that's the problem

Comment: code works for me if I only set different `path` at start (rest of code without changes). I can only say: use `print()` to see values in variables. You have to create corect filenames - maybe use full path instead in `path = "/full/path/to/folder/Desktop/Plot/"`

Comment: you can also use `print(os.getcwd())` to see in which folder you start code - if you run it in different folder then relative path `'../Desktop/Plot/'` will try to get files from different folder then you expect.

Comment: the .../ in my code just represents the file path before, it's not relative pathing. It is the full folder path

Comment: only path which starts with `/` is not relative. Path which starts with `../` is relative.

Comment: I am using path = 'C:\\Users\\vidma\\Desktop\\Plot\\'

Comment: Nothing jumps out to me as being wrong in that though

Comment: path `'C:\\Users\\vidma\\Desktop\\Plot\\'` is full path and you should get full path in `filename` - like 'C:\\Users\\vidma\\Desktop\\Plot\\image.png' - and it should create video file. But it will create `project.avi` in folder in which you run code, not in folder with images.

Comment: ahhh gotcha yeah now that makes sense. Came across another problem however in that the file names are not being sorted out correctly.

C:\Users\vidma\Desktop\Plot\8900.png
C:\Users\vidma\Desktop\Plot\900.png       <------
C:\Users\vidma\Desktop\Plot\9000.png

Comment: python always sort it as strings not numbers - you should create filenames with the same number of digits - `0900` instead of `900` - and then it sorts correctly. OR you will have to write own method to sort it - it will have to get number from filename, convert to `int()` and compare integer values.